# Use a function argument as an object key value

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
let commands = {
  help: () => consoleDialog('defaultMessage'),
  ls: () => consoleDialog('defaultMessage2')
};
```

How can I use an argument as a key identifier to invoke the function held in value:

```
function changeText(currentValue) {
  commands.currentValue()
}
```

In the example above, if currentValue is equal to help, then commands.help() should be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like..

```
let commands = {
  help: () => console.log("defaultMessage"),
  ls: () => console.log("defaultMessage2")
};

function changeText(currentValue) {
  // takes the property of the object dynamically
  commands[currentValue]();
}

changeText("help");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function currentValue(){return "help"}
let currentValue2 = "help"
function changeText(currentValue) {
    commands[currentValue()]()
    commands[currentValue2]()
}
```